# Need a way to emulate PHP crypt() Function in vba

Tags: php, vba, hash, vbscript, hashalgorithm

I have this function in PHP

```
public function hashPassword($password) {
    return crypt($password, '$2a$07$twfAAA1954npfBBB1982oo');
}
```

It have stored passwords in a DB. and I am converting this DB to use Access as a front end instead of PHP and HTML. I need VBA / vbscript code that will convert an entered password and if it is the same password, match the output from the above function.

I have tried all normal hash algorithms and none of them work. I'm not sure how the crypt function works, but it appears to have some sort of seed value which is `'$2a$07$twfAAA1954npfBBB1982oo'` plus the password. Then it probably uses some standard hash algorithm.

Can some one give me the code, or at least tell me how the crypt function uses that seed value so that i can recreate the `crypt()` function in vba?

I found the source code for the crypt function but I'm not strong enough in my knowledge of PHP to understand what really is going on.

Comment: if you can change the php to use md5() instead, it may be easier to match them up...

Comment: I know i wish i could but i can't

Answer (score 0):

About the original function: http://php.net/crypt
So it uses the string you mention as a salt. And the algorithm is: CRYPT_BLOWFISH

And there a few blowfish implementations in VB:

- http://www11.brinkster.com/notbono/vb.asp
- http://www.example-code.com/vbscript/crypt2_blowfish_matchPhp.asp
- http://www.di-mgt.com.au/cryptoBlowfishASP.html

Comment: yes after digging deeper i found that out. But i can't seem to get the values to match up using the blow fish algorithms.  can you help make sense of this. the password is: Truck0409! the salt is: $2a$07$twfAAA1954npfBBB1982oo and the stored password returned from crypt function is:$2a$07$twfAAA1954npfBBB1982oeksSlrRQpws2mkzTSloxQRt4QivN4wha.

Comment: i get the same result from http://www.functions-online.com/crypt.html but cant get it using just a blowfish algorithm.

Comment: I know only the php part. And I don't have environments to test the vb side.